# How to get peer certificate in cowboy_http_handler

Tags: ssl, erlang, ssl-certificate, cowboy

My question for today: is there an **official** way to obtain peer ssl socket information (*peer certificate* to be exact) in *cowboy_http_handler*'s `Handler:handle(Req, State)`?

Of course, I can scrape `Req` tuple (peer socket is the second field as of *today*) with `erlang:element/2`, but this is not future-proof and just doesn't look right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an exported call:

```
cowboy_req:get(socket, Req)
```

It returns the socket, or just about everything else there is in the `Req` object, currently:

```
bindings
body_state
buffer
connection
headers
host
host_info
meta
method
multipart
onresponse
path
path_info
peer
pid
port
qs
resp_body
resp_compress
resp_headers
resp_state
socket
transport
version
```

I'm not sure if it is in the documentation, I can't see it, but it's a lot better and less likely to fail than just getting a numbered element value out, and you can always add a unit test that checks that it works, so if it does get stamped/broken at some point you get a heads up. I don't expect it'll go anywhere though.